# Importing an Xcode project into another one

Tags: xcode

I am trying to integrate one application into another and I thought that a simple way of doing this may be to add the one application into another. (Simply going to File->Add Files to "Project")

However, when I do this and try to use files that are in that other project, it says that the files can not be found. Am I doing something wrong, or is doing this even the correct way of going about this?

Comment: Consider using workspaces. Create a new workspace, copy sources for both apps into the workspace's directory, add apps to the workspace, and set up the dependencies as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could either just import the source files (not the project file itself), or you could make the part of the original project you want to use into a framework (library).  Then you import the entire framework in one step.

Comment: wouldn't creating a framework require some recoding to get everything to work properly?

Comment: Depends on how the application was written.  A framework is just a library and its associated headers.  Assuming there isn't anything much in main.[cc,c,m..] it can be straightforward.  It depends on what "integrate one application into another" means.

Answer (score 2):

You just add the project (project A) and configure it as a dependency of the app (project B).

If it's iOS, you likely want to deal with this shared program using a library.

If OS X, then you still need to link to what symbols you reference (e.g. create a library). If you just want to bundle a helper app or executable with your app, add it as a dependency, then you'll probably want to copy the product (project A.app) as a resource to your bundle of project B.app. If you only want to build or test, then a simple dependency will do.

If you're really sharing sources, look into using a library (static, dynamic, framework) rather than copying your sources or their references.